# Sharepoint develop roadmap

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, architecture

I would like build some service for our team, import some file, parse file, save to sp list, and make some actions with list (for example list peoples who have value more N), build charts and etc.

What i shoud create, new app, or webparts for it? Maybe i shoud create wcf/rest service and create custom page with frontent JS Code?

Comment: Requirements are vague. Where is data comming from? What is the role of SharePoint? Solution depends on SharePoint version (2010, 2013, SharePoint online). Webparts are not possible in SharePoint Online.

Comment: Note that this Q&A site is not a source of FREE consulting services ;-).

Comment: Alexey Krasheninnikov, your comment is inappropriate. Stackoverflow rules not prohibit asking consulting questions. What you mean on consulting? I'm ask technical question.

Comment: W0ut, SP2013 farm, data comming from file what user upload. What types of solutions better for scenarios? For example build visual webpart is better for information widgets...

Answer (score 1):

Some of that can be done using an Access database published to a SharePoint site or linked to SharePoint lists. Anyway you need to finalize and review your requirements with an architect who knows the options within and outside of SharePoint. Don't expect to get a complete set of design decisions explained in response to such vague question.